# What is this filter from an aluminium extrusion facility filtering?

Tags: materials, aluminum

i work for a subcontractor tasked with cleaning these parts from an aluminium extrusion facility.

[image]

essentially we have tried all sorts of different methods when cleaning them and i am just trying to find out what exactly they are filtering in the hopes knowing better what substance we are cleaning from them might point to a more suitable cleaning method.

Any help in this would be appreciated.

edit: for the sake of clarity some of the material gets stuck between the gaps in the filter and is difficult to remove. knowing what that material is, maybe some kind of mould making material for example. Could potentially enable me to soak them in something that would break that material down making cleaning them easier

cheers!

Comment: Particles over a given size. You can infer the particle dimension from the slot gap, or from the waste you remove,

Comment: what is the diameter of the strainers?

Comment: @jsotola 29mm OD

Comment: why don't you ask the customer? ... your company should really have the information about the material that is being filtered ... what if it's hazardous material?

Comment: @jsotola that, of course, if it was an option, would be my first place to go before asking on stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just particulate like others have mentioned; no idea the composition though. Something to consider is that good strainers are often "wedge wire" to reduce particulate getting stuck in the screen. This means that high pressure may clean better from the pressure side of the filter than the filtered side. No idea which is which in this case but something to experiment with.

Usually when I have to clean an unknown object with chemicals, I first try to determine the composition of the object. Once I know the composition, then I know what cleaning chemicals and methods I can use that will not damage the part. This is usually better information that the knowledge of the exact type of contamination (since it is often a mix, thermal degradation, or carbon layer anyways).

From the picture I would guess Brass or Bronze. If that's the case then you instantly know you can uses, water mixtures, surfactant/soap/detergent, alcohols, other organic solvents (Acetone, MEK, Toluene, etc). You can also use a high amount of heat and fairly aggressive pressures from a pressure washer. Temperature can be your friend because different materials have different expansion coefficients. Water soaked carbon can also generate steam pockets when exposed to high heat that will mechanically pop off chunks. Ultrasonic agitation might be an option. Probably better stay away from acids and peroxides unless you are permitted to remove a small amount of the object's surface during the cleaning process.

Good Luck!